# Open popup message before redirect to payment gateway page in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, popup

I wan't to show a popup message to the users before redirect them to my payment gateway page (In my case I use PayU Latam). I made some modifications in the `woocomerce > templates > checkout > payment.php` file with no succes, because although I achieved to make a popup opens, the popup opens but 1 second later redirects to PayU page. I want to find the way to redirect the users to the payment page after they close the popup.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should add your code attempt in your question as this is what we expect from this kind of questions in StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new link for your popup box above the "Place Order" button in payment.php. Then Use CSS to hide the original Place Order button, and use jQuery to trigger it upon clicking the "Confirm" button within your popup message.

Here's an example using jQuery Modal from https://jquerymodal.com/ for the popup box since you didn't provide any code to work with. You can adapt this for the code you already have.

The jQuery to trigger order button click inside the popup:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "a#close_and_confirm_checkout" ).click(function() {
        $( "button#place_order" ).click();
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML for your new "Place Order" button, popup message, and new button to confirm the checkout:

```
<a href="#confirm_checkout" rel="modal:open">Place Order</a>

<div id="confirm_checkout" class="modal">
    <p>Your popup message</p>
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close" id="close_and_confirm_checkout">Confirm Order</a>
</div>
```

Finally hide the original WooCommerce Place Order button in your CSS that will be triggered by our new button inside the Popup box:

```
#place_order { display:none; }
```

Tested and working. You can choose to close the popup box upon clicking the new "Confirm Order" button or not, I think it's best to in case the user has not completed all required fields in the checkout form, but you can always develop this further to check those fields and only close the box if required fields are empty.

Comment: Thank you, so helpful. How I can remove the "out of the box click close" without remove the "X" in the corner, I tried to implement the "un-closable window" effect to the js function but I couldn't. Can you give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm for some reason the example provided isn't working for me either. Don't have much time to find a great solution. Maybe you could ask a new question about it in the JavaScript/jQuery section. Until then, you can use this:

Comment: $('a[href="#confirm_checkout"]').click(function(event) {
    $.modal.defaults = {
    escapeClose: false,      // Allows the user to close the modal by pressing `ESC`
    clickClose: false,       // Allows the user to close the modal by clicking the overlay
    showClose: true,        // Shows a (X) icon/link in the top-right corner
    };
   });